# Django -Email is appearing in console instead of being sent to recipient

Tags: django, email

I am using a business email for my website. Website has two parts, One is "Contact Us" form where email will be sent to my [business email]. Second part requires email to be sent from [business email] to customers emails.

I have set up django mail as per documentation:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'cp1.mywebsitebox.com' 
EMAIL_HOST_USER = '*********' 
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '********'
EMAIL_PORT = 26
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = '*******'
```

Issue is that, first part goes well. Email recieves successfully at [business email] but second part is totally not working. Instead of being sent to recipient, it appears only in console.

Can anyone suggest what the issue is?

Comment: I suggest you post minimally reproducible code: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

it may be issue from your mailing server, can you try gmail server for testing

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = ‘django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend’
EMAIL_HOST = ‘smtp.gmail.com’
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = ‘your_account@gmail.com’
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = ‘your account’s password’
```

and enable less secure app for testing

https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps

Comment: I have tried with gmail account and everything is going great with it. Only issue is with my domain email